# Python search block of lines (with newline character and symbols) and delete them

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, find

I have a text file containing several text bock like below. In that text file, there are another text also. I want to do is find and delete this complete block from the text file (This has symbols, new line character, tab character and text). Can't delete one line by line because those separate lines are in the text file that not meant to delete. I am using Python3.

```
This one:

\begin{itemize}
    \item{first line}
    \item{another line;}
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: you seem to have forgotten to attach your code thats not working and a description of whats not working in your code.

Comment: What is your current approach? Have you any existing Python code for this? Which `itemize` blocks do you want to remove - all of them? Or specific ones? You may instead be interested in a [LaTeX parser](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564420/is-there-a-python-module-for-parsing-latex) in Python to simplify the task.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle i have tried several methods, any of these are working for me. I just need the method to do this, not the entire code.

Comment: @costaparas i tried the replace() function, but it is not working with newline and symbols.Yes i want to find and remove this complete block of text. I will try the latex parser.